# Retrieve nested id using repeated firstchilds in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a web application that dynamically creates and names table elements, and I need to retrieve and parse a thoroughly nested id (not the value). The structure (and my latest attempt) are as such:

```
<table>
      <tr onclick="alert(this.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.id);">
         <td>
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="thisIsTheNeededID">
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
 </table>
```

It keeps returning 'undefined', which confirms my suspicion that I do not know JavaScript as well as I should. I am also using jQuery, so those solutions would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the exact one:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr onclick="alert($(this).find('td:first-child').find('div:first-child').find('input:first-child').attr('id'));">
    <td>
      <div>
        <input type="text" id="thisIsTheNeededID">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This being an inline JavaScript, it is better to use unobtrusive JavaScript by delegating the events and make your code and presentation split, so that it will be clear. A fiddle of unobtrusive JavaScript is below.

```js
$(function () {
  $("table").on("click", "tr", function () {
    alert($(this).find('td:first-child').find('div:first-child').find('input:first-child').attr('id'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <input type="text" id="thisIsTheNeededID">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You don't need to keep on adding code for each `<tr>`.

Comment: You missed `)` of `alert`

Comment: @Tushar Won't you wait? `:O`

Comment: I noticed the same mistake in your other answer, so just added comment :)

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks Praveen. I can't award best answer for a few minutes, but this did it

Comment: Praveen also, recommend the `on` to bind event

Comment: There you go! +1 for `on`